# No origin specified in habitat for rails app

Tags: chef-habitat

I am new to Chef habitat. I followed the tutorial in habitat docs. My rails app is up and running. But when i run the following command:

```
hab plan init -s ruby
```

it says:

```
✗✗✗
✗✗✗ No origin specified
✗✗✗
```

There is no issue or previous questions i found regarding this issue. What should be my next step?

Comment: Changed tag 'habitat' to 'chef-habitat'. Part of effort to split up ambiguous tag 'habitat'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to setup habitat properly.

Run:

```
hab cli setup
```